# Parsing inner XML branch

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, syntax, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<Directories>
    <directory name="name1" info="blahblah" otherInfo="blahblah">
        <file fileName="name"  path="" />
    </directory>

    <directory name="name2" info="blahblah" otherInfo="blahblah">
        <file fileName="name"  path="" />
    </directory>

    <directory name="name3" info="blahblah" otherInfo="blahblah">
        <file fileName="name"  path="" />
    </directory>
</Directories>
```

I am using the following code to parse through the relevant branch to update the directory/file information:

```
XmlDocument objLog = new XmlDocument();
objLog.Load(path);

//update directory info
foreach (XmlNode objNode in objLog.SelectNodes("/Directories/directory"))
{
    XmlElement objUpdatedNode = objLog.CreateElement("directory");
    objUpdatedNode.SetAttribute("name", "NAME");
    objUpdatedNode.SetAttribute("info", "INFO");
    objUpdatedNode.SetAttribute("otherInfo", "OTHERINFO");

    //update file information
    foreach (XmlNode objFileNode in 
             objLog.SelectNodes("/Directories/directory/file"))
    {
        XmlElement objFileNode = objLog.CreateElement("file");
        objFileNode.SetAttribute("fileName", "FILENAME");
        objFileNode.SetAttribute("path", "PATH");

        objLog.SelectNodes("/Directories")[0]
              .ReplaceChild(objUpdatedNode, objNode);         
        objUpdatedNode.AppendChild(objUpdatedFileNode);
    }

    objLog.Save(path);
}
```

The code works just as I expect it to if there is only directory in the XML file, but if I have multiple entries as above, an error is thrown as it tries to parse through the file node multiple times and the XML file is never updated. And if I get rid of the updating file information part of the code, it the directory branch updates correctly. How can I update both the directory and its associated inner file branch?

Comment: What is your code doing? You iterate the list of directories and create them again?  What should it do?

Comment: The code should iterate through the directories branches and update each directory and file branch with some specified input. I'm having issues with updating the inner file branch through each iteration

Comment: you mispelt directories when selecting file nodes. `objLog.SelectNodes("/directores/directory/file")` should be `objLog.SelectNodes("/Directories/directory/file")`

Comment: I fixed the spelling mistake in the post, but it's unrelated to my problem. Any ideas on why the inner xml branch is not updating and throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create/remove elements.  Simply update them in place as follows

```
XmlDocument objLog = new XmlDocument();
objLog.Load(path);

//update directory info
foreach (XmlElement objNode in objLog.SelectNodes("/Directories/directory"))
{
    objNode.SetAttribute("name", "NAME");
    objNode.SetAttribute("info", "INFO");
    objNode.SetAttribute("otherInfo", "OTHERINFO");

    //update file information
    foreach (XmlElement objFileNode in objNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        objFileNode.SetAttribute("fileName", "FILENAME");
        objFileNode.SetAttribute("path", "PATH");
    }
}

// Done Updating - Save
objLog.Save(path);
```

I have altered the `foreach` loops to use `XmlElement` which gives you access to `SetAttribute` method.  The loop simply iterates over the nodes and updates.